# BGL Adding an edge with multiple properties

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I want to have all edges have to properties, weight and capacity.  I found that BGL has these both already defined.  So I define Edge and Vertex properties for the Graph

```
 typedef property<vertex_name_t, string> VertexProperty;
 typedef property<edge_weight_t, int, property<edge_capacity_t, int> > EdgeProperty;
 typedef adjacency_list<listS,vecS, undirectedS, VertexProperty, EdgeProperty > Graph;
```

Here is where I am trying to add the edges to the graph:

```
172: EdgeProperty prop = (weight, capacity);
173: add_edge(vertex1,vertex2, prop, g);
```

If I had just 1 property I know it would be prop = 5; However, with two I am confused about the formatting.

Here is the error I am receiving:

```
graph.cc: In function ‘void con_graph()’:
graph.cc:172: warning: left-hand operand of comma has no effect
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the implementation of [boost::property](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/boost/pending/property.hpp) you'll see that a property value cannot be initialized this way. And even then, the syntax you have `(weight, capacity)` is not valid anyways, so, if it was possible to initialize the property like that, it would be written `EdgeProperty prop = EdgeProperty(weight, capacity);` or just `EdgeProperty prop(weight, capacity);`. But, again, that won't work. Technically, this is the way you would need to initialize the property value:

```
EdgeProperty prop = EdgeProperty(weight, property<edge_capacity_t, int>(capacity));
```

But this is kind of ugly as the number of properties increase. So, it would be cleaner to default-construct the edge-property and then manually set each individual property:

```
EdgeProperty prop;
get_property_value(prop, edge_weight_t) = weight;
get_property_value(prop, edge_capacity_t) = capacity;
```

Of course, the better alternative is to use bundled properties instead of the older boost::property chains.

Comment: could you give an example for bundled properties of latest boost graph library?

Answer (score 0):

The correct form is:

```
EdgeProperty prop;
get_property_value(prop, edge_weight) = weight;
get_property_value(prop, edge_capacity) = capacity;
```