# astar_search on a graph with listS as the vertex container?

Tags: c++, boost, graph, a-star, boost-graph

It seems that `boost::astar_search` doesn't like graphs with `boost::listS` as the vertex container.

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::listS,
    boost::listS,
    boost::undirectedS,
    WaypointNode,
    boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float> >
Waypoint;
```

The graph definition above compiles normally when I changed the second template parameter into `boost::vecS` while it refuses to compile when I use `boost::listS`.

I'm not really sure (since template error messages refuse to be understood by normal human beings) but it seems the problem is because the algorithm needs access to `operator[]` for some reason. Which doesn't exist if you do use `listS`. I'm not really sure why random access is required since conceptually you can see which neighbor exist for a particular vertex from the edge list anyway.

Is there anything I can do to make `astar_search` accepts `listS`?

EDIT:
here's the error message when trying to compile (using `g++`) the above code. Mind you that it compiles fine when I changed the second `boost::listS` into `boost::vecS`

this line is interesting in particular i.e. it seems to complain about (or lack thereof) `operator[]`

```
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.49.0/include/boost/property_map/shared_array_property_map.hpp: In member function 'T& boost::shared_array_property_map<T, IndexMap>::operator[](typename boost::property_traits<IndexMap>::key_type) const [with T = boost::default_color_type, IndexMap = boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t>]'
```

this is the complete (and unwieldy) error messages:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.49.0/include/boost/property_map/shared_array_property_map.hpp: In member function 'T& boost::shared_array_property_map<T, IndexMap>::operator[](typename boost::property_traits<IndexMap>::key_type) const [with T = boost::default_color_type, IndexMap = boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t>]':
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.49.0/include/boost/property_map/property_map.hpp:361:   instantiated from 'void boost::put(const boost::put_get_helper<Reference, PropertyMap>&, K, const V&) [with PropertyMap = boost::shared_array_property_map<boost::default_color_type, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >, Reference = boost::default_color_type&, K = void*, V = boost::default_color_type]'
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.49.0/include/boost/graph/astar_search.hpp:288:   instantiated from 'void boost::astar_search(const VertexListGraph&, typename boost::graph_traits<G>::vertex_descriptor, AStarHeuristic, AStarVisitor, PredecessorMap, CostMap, DistanceMap, WeightMap, VertexIndexMap, ColorMap, CompareFunction, CombineFunction, CostInf, CostZero) [with VertexListGraph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, AStarHeuristic = DistanceHeuristic<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS> >, AStarVisitor = WaypointNodeVisitor<void*>, PredecessorMap = boost::dummy_property_map, CostMap = boost::shared_array_property_map<float, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >, DistanceMap = boost::shared_array_property_map<float, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >, WeightMap = boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::undirected_tag, float, const float&, void*, const boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::edge_weight_t>, VertexIndexMap = boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t>, ColorMap = boost::shared_array_property_map<boost::default_color_type, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >, CompareFunction = std::less<float>, CombineFunction = boost::closed_plus<float>, CostInf = float, CostZero = float]'
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.49.0/include/boost/graph/astar_search.hpp:330:   instantiated from 'void boost::astar_search(const VertexListGraph&, typename boost::graph_traits<G>::vertex_descriptor, AStarHeuristic, const boost::bgl_named_params<P, T, R>&) [with VertexListGraph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, AStarHeuristic = DistanceHeuristic<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS> >, P = WaypointNodeVisitor<void*>, T = boost::graph_visitor_t, R = boost::no_property]'
Pathfinding.h:28:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.49.0/include/boost/property_map/shared_array_property_map.hpp:36: error: no match for 'operator[]' in '((const boost::shared_array_property_map<boost::default_color_type, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >*)this)->boost::shared_array_property_map<boost::default_color_type, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >::data[boost::get [with PropertyMap = boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t>, Reference = const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, K = void*](((const boost::put_get_helper<const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >&)((const boost::put_get_helper<const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >*)(&((const boost::shared_array_property_map<boost::default_color_type, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >*)this)->boost::shared_array_property_map<boost::default_color_type, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >::index))), ((void* const&)((void* const*)(& v))))]'
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.49.0/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_array.hpp:103: note: candidates are: T& boost::shared_array<T>::operator[](ptrdiff_t) const [with T = boost::default_color_type]
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.49.0/include/boost/property_map/shared_array_property_map.hpp: In member function 'T& boost::shared_array_property_map<T, IndexMap>::operator[](typename boost::property_traits<IndexMap>::key_type) const [with T = float, IndexMap = boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t>]':
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.49.0/include/boost/property_map/property_map.hpp:361:   instantiated from 'void boost::put(const boost::put_get_helper<Reference, PropertyMap>&, K, const V&) [with PropertyMap = boost::shared_array_property_map<float, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >, Reference = float&, K = void*, V = float]'
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.49.0/include/boost/graph/astar_search.hpp:289:   instantiated from 'void boost::astar_search(const VertexListGraph&, typename boost::graph_traits<G>::vertex_descriptor, AStarHeuristic, AStarVisitor, PredecessorMap, CostMap, DistanceMap, WeightMap, VertexIndexMap, ColorMap, CompareFunction, CombineFunction, CostInf, CostZero) [with VertexListGraph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, AStarHeuristic = DistanceHeuristic<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS> >, AStarVisitor = WaypointNodeVisitor<void*>, PredecessorMap = boost::dummy_property_map, CostMap = boost::shared_array_property_map<float, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >, DistanceMap = boost::shared_array_property_map<float, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >, WeightMap = boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::undirected_tag, float, const float&, void*, const boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::edge_weight_t>, VertexIndexMap = boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t>, ColorMap = boost::shared_array_property_map<boost::default_color_type, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >, CompareFunction = std::less<float>, CombineFunction = boost::closed_plus<float>, CostInf = float, CostZero = float]'
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.49.0/include/boost/graph/astar_search.hpp:330:   instantiated from 'void boost::astar_search(const VertexListGraph&, typename boost::graph_traits<G>::vertex_descriptor, AStarHeuristic, const boost::bgl_named_params<P, T, R>&) [with VertexListGraph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, AStarHeuristic = DistanceHeuristic<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS> >, P = WaypointNodeVisitor<void*>, T = boost::graph_visitor_t, R = boost::no_property]'
Pathfinding.h:28:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.49.0/include/boost/property_map/shared_array_property_map.hpp:36: error: no match for 'operator[]' in '((const boost::shared_array_property_map<float, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >*)this)->boost::shared_array_property_map<float, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >::data[boost::get [with PropertyMap = boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t>, Reference = const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, K = void*](((const boost::put_get_helper<const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >&)((const boost::put_get_helper<const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >*)(&((const boost::shared_array_property_map<float, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >*)this)->boost::shared_array_property_map<float, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >::index))), ((void* const&)((void* const*)(& v))))]'
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.49.0/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_array.hpp:103: note: candidates are: T& boost::shared_array<T>::operator[](ptrdiff_t) const [with T = float]
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.49.0/include/boost/property_map/vector_property_map.hpp: In member function 'typename std::iterator_traits<typename std::vector<T, std::allocator<_CharT> >::iterator>::reference boost::vector_property_map<T, IndexMap>::operator[](const typename boost::property_traits<IndexMap>::key_type&) const [with T = long unsigned int, IndexMap = boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t>]':
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.49.0/include/boost/property_map/property_map.hpp:361:   instantiated from 'void boost::put(const boost::put_get_helper<Reference, PropertyMap>&, K, const V&) [with PropertyMap = boost::vector_property_map<long unsigned int, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >, Reference = long unsigned int&, K = void*, V = size_t]'
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.49.0/include/boost/graph/detail/d_ary_heap.hpp:118:   instantiated from 'void boost::d_ary_heap_indirect<Value, Arity, IndexInHeapPropertyMap, DistanceMap, Compare, Container>::push(const Value&) [with Value = void*, long unsigned int Arity = 4ul, IndexInHeapPropertyMap = boost::vector_property_map<long unsigned int, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >, DistanceMap = boost::shared_array_property_map<float, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >, Compare = std::less<float>, Container = std::vector<void*, std::allocator<void*> >]'
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.49.0/include/boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp:74:   instantiated from 'void boost::breadth_first_visit(const IncidenceGraph&, typename boost::graph_traits<G>::vertex_descriptor, Buffer&, BFSVisitor, ColorMap) [with IncidenceGraph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, Buffer = boost::d_ary_heap_indirect<void*, 4ul, boost::vector_property_map<long unsigned int, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >, boost::shared_array_property_map<float, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >, std::less<float>, std::vector<void*, std::allocator<void*> > >, BFSVisitor = boost::detail::astar_bfs_visitor<DistanceHeuristic<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS> >, WaypointNodeVisitor<void*>, boost::d_ary_heap_indirect<void*, 4ul, boost::vector_property_map<long unsigned int, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >, boost::shared_array_property_map<float, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >, std::less<float>, std::vector<void*, std::allocator<void*> > >, boost::dummy_property_map, boost::shared_array_property_map<float, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >, boost::shared_array_property_map<float, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >, boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::undirected_tag, float, const float&, void*, const boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::edge_weight_t>, boost::shared_array_property_map<boost::default_color_type, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >, boost::closed_plus<float>, std::less<float> >, ColorMap = boost::shared_array_property_map<boost::default_color_type, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >]'
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.49.0/include/boost/graph/astar_search.hpp:260:   instantiated from 'void boost::astar_search_no_init(const VertexListGraph&, typename boost::graph_traits<G>::vertex_descriptor, AStarHeuristic, AStarVisitor, PredecessorMap, CostMap, DistanceMap, WeightMap, ColorMap, VertexIndexMap, CompareFunction, CombineFunction, CostInf, CostZero) [with VertexListGraph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, AStarHeuristic = DistanceHeuristic<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS> >, AStarVisitor = WaypointNodeVisitor<void*>, PredecessorMap = boost::dummy_property_map, CostMap = boost::shared_array_property_map<float, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >, DistanceMap = boost::shared_array_property_map<float, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >, WeightMap = boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::undirected_tag, float, const float&, void*, const boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::edge_weight_t>, ColorMap = boost::shared_array_property_map<boost::default_color_type, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >, VertexIndexMap = boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, WaypointNode, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t>, CompareFunction = std::less<float>, CombineFunction = boost::closed_plus<float>, CostInf = float, CostZero = float]'

make[2]: *** [build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/BotManager.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

Comment: Can you post the template error messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t` that's the important part of the error. Only adjacency lists with vecS as their VertexList have an internal vertex_index property map by default. If you really want to use a listS (I believe the only advantage it has is that the removal of vertices is simpler) you need to either create an internal vertex index property map by using `boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, int, WaypointNode>` in your graph declaration and then initialize it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277820/bgl-adding-an-edge-with-multiple-properties) or [this](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/BGL-add-vertex-vp-graph-with-mix-of-internal-amp-bundled-properties-td2571055.html):

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::listS,
    boost::listS,
    boost::undirectedS,
    boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, int, WaypointNode>,
    boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float> >
Waypoint;
Waypoint waypoint_graph;
...
add_vertex(boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, int,WaypointNode>(0, waypoint_node_0), graph);
add_vertex(boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, int,WaypointNode>(1, waypoint_node_1), graph);
...
astar_search(waypoint_graph, start, my_heuristic, boost::visitor(my_visitor));
```

or you can create an external vertex index property map, initalize it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8555715/1252091) and then invoke `astar_search` with the named parameter `vertex_index_map`:

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::listS,
    boost::listS,
    boost::undirectedS,
    WaypointNode,
    boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float> >
Waypoint;
Waypoint waypoint_graph;
...
add_vertex(waypoint_node_0, graph);
add_vertex(waypoint_node_1, graph);
...
typedef map<typename boost::graph_traits<Waypoint>::vertex_descriptor, size_t> IndexMap;
IndexMap mapIndex;
associative_property_map<IndexMap> propmapIndex(mapIndex);
size_t i=0;
BGL_FORALL_VERTICES(v, waypoint_graph, Waypoing)
{
   put(propmapIndex, v, i++);
}
...
astar_search(waypoint_graph, start, my_heuristic, boost::visitor(my_visitor).vertex_index_map(propmapIndex));
```

This problem is not exclusive to `astar_search` and both of these solutions can be used with most algorithms in the Boost.Graph library.

Comment: I think these are definitely the solutions I'm looking for!

Comment: Might I add that it is more efficient with vecS indeed and if you want to do heavy A* pathfinding you should go with that. I'm only looking for this solution because in the game i'm creating we'll be able to edit the waypoint map on the fly and it's easier to work with listS to test it (before i finalize it into a vecS structure after testing)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a 100% sure but I think I tested astar_search once before with listS. I replaced the vecS of the following graph-type:

`boost::adjacency_list < boost::vecS, boost::vecS,
        boost::directedS, boost::no_property,
        boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, Cost> >`

I found an [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/graph/example/dijkstra-example-listS.cpp) doing a Dijkstra's shortest path on an adjecency_list that uses listS. Have a look at that. My example compiled after commenting out a lot of stuff that depends on vectors, however it still has issues with the predecessor_map and distance_map. The example replaces those using a property_map.

Comment: Thanks. I read how you mentioned that the vertex container needs to have vertex_index property and it might be the answer. I will also look at how the dijkstra can use listS.